# Three.js - how to create custom shapes

Tags: javascript, three.js

I´m using Three.js and trying to create some custom shapes, similar to one that appears in a project from one of agencies using threejs:

**three.js featured project esample** [image: threejs featured project]

How did they generated these boxes with holes inside? (on that examples
boxes basically have only borders around and are empty inside).

> As I saw in the code (I was trying to figure out myself) they use  **BoxGeometry** but I have no idea how to accomplish that. Does anyone know or can give me any directions? It would be really helpfull as i´m stuck with this and have no idea on how to create them.

Answer (score 1):

So in THREE.js Meshes represent any kind of 3D object. They combine Geometries and Shaders. Generally to create a mesh you call

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, shader );
```

If you use any of the builtin shaders (also known as Materials [ MeshBasicMaterial, MeshLambertMaterial, etc]) they have a wireFrame boolean attribute that allows this functionality.

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( x, y, z ),
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { 
        wireFrame: true, // This makes the object appear wireframe
        color: 0xffffff  // You can alter other properties
    });

var box = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

// You can also change it later
box.material.wireFrame = false;
```